# Controller function called 2 times at the same time MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

my controller is called twice at the same time, i don't know what's wrong with the code

Controller:

```
List<Item> lstItems = new List<Item>();
public ActionResult _SaveItem(ItemDetails model)
        {
            Item it = new Item();
            it.ItemName = model.itemName;
            it.ItemURL = model.itemUrl;
            it.Notes = model.Notes;
            it.Price = model.unitprice;
            it.Quantity = model.quantity;
            it.Size = model.Size;
            it.Weight = model.weight;
            it.CategoryID = model.CategoryID;
            it.Color = model.color;
            lstItems.Add(it);
            return PartialView(it);
        }
```

View:

```
@model CSP1225.Models.ItemDetails

@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("_SaveItem", "Order", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId="Items" }))
    {
        <div id="Items">                                  
        </div>
          <div class="form-horizontal" style="padding-left:20px;" > 
              @Html.EditorForModel()

            <input type="Submit" id="addItem" value="Add Item" name="addItem" />
        </div>

}
```

any help please.. ??

Comment: How are you seeing that it's called twice at the same time?

Comment: When is it called twice? On submit or load?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it appears the item added in `<div id="Items">` and breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Actually i included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` Twice , that's why the code called twice at the same time :)